# Twig Cache: What exactly are cached?

Tags: caching, twig, template-engine, silex

I am testing Silex framework with Twig template (not using Symfony 2 framework). I see turning on Twig cache does speed up 40%, but my question is what stuff are cached? Does it only cache the HTML structure? What about the dynamic data loaded from database and/or a text file by PHP's file_get_contents() function?

I also have question about auto_reload option, from the documentation it days

```
"auto_reload: When developing with Twig, 
it's useful to recompile the template whenever
the source code changes. If you don't provide a
value for the auto_reload option, it will be
determined automatically based on the debug value."
```

What does source code here referring to? Data or HTML structure? Does it depend on how Twig filter tags are defined for display?

Thank you.

Comment: It caches the compile twig templates. You can just check your template cache to see what's in there.